# Как добавить элементы поиска в value тег input без обновлении страницы

Tags: php, html, html5

Здравствуйте как можно добавить элементы поиска в  value тег input без обновлении страницы чтобы в дальнейшем можно было записать в БД. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Чтобы когда пользователь нажал на результат поиска и этот текст появился на input без обновлений.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
 $('p').click(function(){ // отлавливаем нажатие на результат поиска
  var adres = $(this).text(); // получаем текст который соответствует выбраному нами результату поиска
  $("#poisk").attr("value", adres); //записываем текст в инпут (меняем значение value)
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="poisk" />
<p>Результат 1</p>
<p>Результат 2</p>
<p>Результат 3</p>
<p>Результат 4</p>
```